# SPSS Identifying Different Lagged Values Through Loops

Tags: loops, lag, spss

I have this dataset with 2 variables: week and brand_chosen, where brand chosen designates which product from e.g. a super market was chosen, an it looks like this.

```
Week     brand_chosen
 2           19
 2           15    
 2           50
 2           12
 3           19
 3           16
 3           50
 4           77
 4           19
```

What I am trying to do is for each line, to note the week in which the brand purchase was made, and check if in the week before that the same brand purchase was made. In case it did, a variable *dummy* would take the value of 1, otherwise 0.
Because week appears multiple times I cannot take just the lag(week,1), so I probably need to loop through the week variables for each case, until it finds the first different value.

This is what i tried to do

```
loop i=1 to 70.  
   do if (week<>lag(week,i) and brand_chosen=lag(brand_chosen,i)).  
      compute dummy=1.  
   end loop.  
   else.  
      compute dummy=0.  
   end if.  
end loop.  
execute.
```

Where 70 is just an arbitrary number so that I am sure that it will check all the previous cases.
I get two problems with that. First the lag function needs to contain a number from what I understand but "i" is not considered a number here.
The second problem is that i would like to close the loop if the condition is satisfied, and move to the next case but I get an error.

I am new to spss syntax and I am struggling with that one, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be helpful if you provide corresponding output for your example and/or pseudo code of the loop as you would implement it.

Comment: @lossleader I 've edited my comment providing some more info if it can be of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that every combination of week--brand_chosen is unique. In this case the solution is quite simple. Just reorder your dataset by brand_chosen and then week, and then run a simple lag command.

This should do the trick:

```
SORT CASES BY brand_chosen week.
COMPUTE dummy=0.
IF (brand_chosen=LAG(brand_chosen) AND week>LAG(week)) dummy = 1.
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer.  

Sorry I should have mentioned that each combination of weeks-brands is not unique. So in a scenario that two consecutive cases have the same week and the same brand, only the first of these two cases will have the dummy=1.  

Also the thing is that in some cases the week could go from "week 50" to "week 56" so the weeks do not appear in a consecutive order.

Comment: > "So in a scenario that two consecutive cases have the same week and the same brand, only the first of these two cases will have the dummy=1" If this is the outpunt you want to achieve, everything is fine, because the code will do exactly that.

Comment: > "Also the thing is that in some cases the week could go from "week 50" to "week 56" so the weeks do not appear in a consecutive order." I changed the operator in the if-statement. Hope this will satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Although I am still curious if I could use "i" as in LAG(week,i) in the loop above somehow. Thanks again

Comment: I think the LAG(var,i) construct works inside of a macro loop. But I havn't tested it yet.